# Dynamic add form fields depending the value

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

In my Django application I have the form with 'rooms' field, it is integer field. Depending on numbers of rooms i want to generate two another fields for each room 'adult' and 'children'. I saw many examples how to do this on java-script, so i try to write the script by my self, but it doesn't work. And there is no errors on browser. I am newbie in java-script, can you tell me what i'm doing wrong

`Here is my html file`

```
<div class="fieldWrapper">
    <label for="id_rooms">Rooms:</label>
    <input id="id_rooms" type="number" name="rooms" min="1">
</div>
```

`js file:`

```
$(function() {

    var newFields = $('');
    $('#id_rooms').bind('blur keyup change', function() {
        var n = this.value || 0;
        if (n + 1) {
            if (n > newFields.length) {
                addFields(n);
            } else {
                removeFields(n);
            }
        }
    });

    function addFields(n) {
        for (form_num = newFields.lenght; form_num < n; form_num++) {
            $("input[id='id_form-TOTAL_FORMS']").attr('value', form_num + 1);
            $(".extrafieldWrapper").append("<br/><label for='id_form-" + form_num + "-adult'>Adult:</label> <input id='id_form-" + form_num + "-adult' type='number' name='form-" + form_num + "-adult'/> <label for='id_form-" + form_num + "-children'>Children:</label> <input id='id_form-" + form_num + "-children' type='number'  name='form-" + form_num + "-children'/> ");
        }
    }

    function removeFields(n) {
        var removeField = newFields.slice(n).remove();
        newFields = newFields.not(removeField);
    }
});
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: It seems you also use JQuery. Did you add some reference to the library ? https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/#jquery

Comment: what is this `var newFields = $('');` ?

Comment: newFields.lenght -> length

Comment: It creates a new, empty, jquery, variable.
I did not read the code yet, but you should also probably wrap it into a $(document).ready(function() { CODE }); in order to be sure that DOM has already loaded when you begin to manipulate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML -

```
<div class="fieldWrapper">
<label for="id_rooms">Rooms:</label>
<input id="id_rooms" type="number" name="rooms" min="1">
</div>

<div class="extrafieldWrapper">    
</div>
```

Javascript -

```
$(function() {

var newFields = $('');
$('#id_rooms').bind('blur keyup change', function() {
    var n = this.value || 0;
    if (n + 1) {
        if (n > newFields.length) {
            addFields(n);
        } else {
            removeFields(n);
        }
    }
});

function addFields(n) {
    for (form_num = newFields.length; form_num < n; form_num++) { // lenght->length
        $("input[id='id_form-TOTAL_FORMS']").attr('value', form_num + 1);
        $(".extrafieldWrapper").append("<br/><label for='id_form-" + form_num + "-adult'>Adult:</label> <input id='id_form-" + form_num + "-adult' type='number' name='form-" + form_num + "-adult'/> <label for='id_form-" + form_num + "-children'>Children:</label> <input id='id_form-" + form_num + "-children' type='number'  name='form-" + form_num + "-children'/> ");
    }
}

function removeFields(n) {
    var removeField = newFields.slice(n).remove();
    newFields = newFields.not(removeField);
}
} );
```

Answer (score 1):

HTML

```
<div class="fieldWrapper">
    <label for="id_rooms">Rooms:</label>
    <input id="id_rooms" type="number" name="rooms" min="1">
</div>
<div class="extrafieldWrapper"></div>
```

JS

```
$(function() {

var newFields = $('');
$('#id_rooms').bind('blur keyup change', function() {
    var n = this.value || 0;
    if (n + 1) {
        if (n > newFields.length) {
            addFields(n);
        } else {
            removeFields(n);
        }
    }
});

function addFields(n) {
    for (form_num = newFields.length; form_num < n; form_num++) { // lenght->length
        $("input[id='id_form-TOTAL_FORMS']").attr('value', form_num + 1);
        $(".extrafieldWrapper").append("<br/><label for='id_form-" + form_num + "-adult'>Adult:</label> <input id='id_form-" + form_num + "-adult' type='number' name='form-" + form_num + "-adult'/> <label for='id_form-" + form_num + "-children'>Children:</label> <input id='id_form-" + form_num + "-children' type='number'  name='form-" + form_num + "-children'/> ");
    }
}

function removeFields(n) {
    $('.extrafieldWrapper').html('');
}

});
```

Here is a fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/ymz60pjm/